# Sending email with node and express

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

So i have this small node server where i try to send an email like this

```
app.post('/messaggio', function(req, res) {
   var textMessage = req.body.message;
   var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       Service : 'Gmail',
       auth : {
          user : 'myemail01@gmail.com',
          pass : 'mypassword'
       }
   });

   var mailOptions = {
      from: 'myemail@gmail.com',
      to : 'receiver3@gmail.com',
      subject : "My SUBJECT",
      text : textMessage
   }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      else {        
        console.log("message sent");
      }
  });
});
```

I deplyed it on heroku but on /messaggio request i get this messages in the heroku logs:

app[web.1]: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587

app[web.1]:     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)

app[web.1]:     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)

app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)

app[web.1]:   code: 'ECONNECTION',

app[web.1]:   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',

app[web.1]:   syscall: 'connect',

app[web.1]:   address: '127.0.0.1',

app[web.1]:   port: 587,

app[web.1]:   command: 'CONN' }

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: It works on other routes? This does not seem to be related with emails, but network

Comment: i followed this tutorial http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/07/02/send-email-node-js-express/

Comment: Looks like nodemail doesn't take service as an option anymore.

Comment: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

Comment: Maybe Heroku block smtp ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});
```